# Flask_socketio emit data from server side to front web page behind a reverse proxy

Tags: flask-socketio

all,
I currently encounter a problem that blocked me many days. Currently my flask server runs behind a reverse proxy, I can emit data from web page using javascript ajax socket.io, but when I want to send data from flask server side to the webpage, it does not work.
If there is no reverse proxy, and the data communication works well.
Here is the code:
Front end:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + "/edc/" ); 
        
// Update the graph with new data received from the server
socket.on('new_data', function (data) {
    console.log("new data comes");

    // Update the graph
                
});
```

Server side:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

def generate_data():
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # Update interval (in seconds)
        #logger.Info(" new Data in Thread")
        #prepare data
        ...
        socketio.emit('new_data', {'x': x, 'y':y, 'z':z, 'temp':temp, 'time':time.time()})

data_thread = Thread(target=generate_data, daemon=True)
data_thread.start()
socketio.run(app, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
```

Please give me some suggestion, thank you so much!

I tried to add a path parameter when I create the flask socketio, but it did not work.
I expected that the web page can get the data from the server.

Comment: See the troubleshooting section of the Flask-SocketIO documentation to learn how to enable debug logs. Then add a log session to your question, which will help understand what your application is doing.